# malformed header from script. Bad header=<br />: index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is I'm asked to fix a website that can't be opened. So when I open the site theres a notif like

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mywebsite.com
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've tried to look for 500 Internal Sever and I don't find a good solution. So I called the host administrator and they send me the error log :

> malformed header from script. Bad header=`<br />`: index.php

But when I check in the index.php there isn't any `<br />` tag inside the index.php. Here's the index.php

```
<?php

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| PHP ERROR REPORTING LEVEL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CI runs with error reporting set to ALL.  For security
| reasons you are encouraged to change this when your site goes live.
| For more info visit:  http://www.php.net/error_reporting
|
*/
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
| Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
| as this file.
|
| NO TRAILING SLASH!
|
*/
    $system_folder = "system";

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
| folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder 
| can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.
| For more info please see the user guide:
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
|
|
| NO TRAILING SLASH!
|
*/
    $application_folder = "application";

/*
|===============================================================
| END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS
|===============================================================
*/


/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| SET THE SERVER PATH
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Let's attempt to determine the full-server path to the "system"
| folder in order to reduce the possibility of path problems.
| Note: We only attempt this if the user hasn't specified a 
| full server path.
|
*/
if (strpos($system_folder, '/') === FALSE)
{
    if (function_exists('realpath') AND @realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
    }
}
else
{
    // Swap directory separators to Unix style for consistency
    $system_folder = str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder); 
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| DEFINE APPLICATION CONSTANTS
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| EXT       - The file extension.  Typically ".php"
| SELF      - The name of THIS file (typically "index.php")
| FCPATH    - The full server path to THIS file
| BASEPATH  - The full server path to the "system" folder
| APPPATH   - The full server path to the "application" folder
|
*/
define('EXT', '.php');
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');

if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ($application_folder == '')
    {
        $application_folder = 'application';
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| LOAD THE FRONT CONTROLLER
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| And away we go...
|
*/
require_once BASEPATH.'codeigniter/CodeIgniter'.EXT;

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

So I don't know where's the problem and what does that error log mean about the `<br />`. Can some help me about this problem? I'm new in codeigniter and new in stack overflow so sorry if my question isn't clear enough. Thanks before

EDIT :
Here's the config.php :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
$config['admin_url'] = $config['base_url'] . "/admin/";
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
#$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
#$config['index_page'] = "ciwismel.php?";
$config['index_page'] = "";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of "AUTO" works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
//$config['uri_protocol']    = "CI_PATH";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = "";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = "english";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable System Hooks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you would like to use the "hooks" feature you must enable it by
| setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
|
*/
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Extension Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
| native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
|
*/
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string "words" that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to 
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/logs/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date Format for Logs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
| codes to set your own date formatting
|
*/
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/cache/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class or the Sessions class with encryption
| enabled you MUST set an encryption key.  See the user guide for info.
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = "";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'session_cookie_name' = the name you want for the cookie
| 'encrypt_sess_cookie' = TRUE/FALSE (boolean).  Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'session_expiration'  = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|  by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'time_to_update'      = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Output Compression
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
| the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
| Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
| so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
|
| VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
| means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
| even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
| compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
| by the output class.  Do not "echo" any values with compression enabled.
|
*/
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are "local" or "gmt".  This pref tells the system whether to use
| your server's local time as the master "now" reference, or convert it to
| GMT.  See the "date helper" page of the user guide for information
| regarding date handling.
|
*/
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
*/
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reverse Proxy IPs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy IP
| addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
| header in order to properly identify the visitor's IP address.
| Comma-delimited, e.g. '10.0.1.200,10.0.1.201'
|
*/
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/config.php */
```

Oh another problem is this site wasn't built by me before

Comment: Look for `header` function in any controller that doesn't work and give us code.

Comment: Please make sure your file structure is correct. and then check the sys path and app path.

Comment: Could you share application/config/config.php file ?

Comment: How old is this site and which versions of PHP and Code Igniter does it use?

It may be a simple version conflict if PHP was updated and the CI is old version etc.

The problem could be the PHP using something removed like register_globals or ini problem like magic_quotes_cpg.

Comment: it's about 7-10 years from what they said. And I don't know what CI version It is but It could be version 2.x. So do you mean I should bring it to newer CI version? @DocWeird

Comment: It might be that your server admin updated his PHP which broke the old CI. Upgrading 2.x to 3.x is *not* trivial. And that is way out of the scope of this question and well documented elsewhere.

I suggest you first check your CI and PHP versions and their compatibility - this will tell you if this problem is correctable without version updates.